# How to do calculation inside <asp:Gridview>

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code to display list of data. I need to calculate the total.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvS" runat="server" DataKeyNames="DateCheckIn" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable dataTable no-footer" EmptyDataText="No bookings found." OnRowDataBound="gvS_RowDataBound">
    <FooterStyle Font-Bold="true" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Check-In Date / Payment Date" DataField="DateCheckIn" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Room Sales" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lRoom" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", Eval("Room")) %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="POS" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lPos" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", Eval("Pos")) %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shower" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lShower" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", Eval("Shower")) %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        // Total = lRoom + lPos + lShower
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to calculate the Total (at the right side) which equal to lRoom + lPos + lShower. I manage to get Total for the footer.

The following is my gvS_rowDataBound

```
protected void gvS_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lRoom = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lRoom");
        Label lPos = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lPos");
        Label lShower = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lShower");

        decimal amount = 0;

        if (decimal.TryParse(lRoom.Text, out amount))
            totalRoomSales += amount;

        if (decimal.TryParse(lPos.Text, out amount))
            totalPosSales += amount;

        if (decimal.TryParse(lShower.Text, out amount))
            totalShowerSales += amount;

    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", totalRoomSales);
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", totalPosSales);
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", totalShowerSales);
     }
}
```

The output should be something like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Item | Check-In Date | Room Sales | POS | Shower | Total |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | 01/01/2019    |   100.00   | 5.00| 8.00   | 113.00|
| 2    | 02/01/2019    |    50.00   | 2.00| 3.50   |  55.50|
------------------------------------------------------------
|      |               |   150.00   | 7.00|11.50   | 168.50|
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Help me to get the total please.. Thanks

Comment: UI elements aren't really designed for doing maths on. Their purpose is just to display things and handle user interaction. They don't make it easy for you to write simple calculation code. Consider looking at the source data which you bind to the GridView (e.g. maybe it's a datatable, or a List or something), and using that as the source data for your calculations. Then you can get that data and append it to your gridview separately - possibly putting it in the footer section would be sensible.

Comment: @ADyson the thing is.. the data is from SQL.. and if i calculate in SQL.. it will auto truncate/rounding the value which is not correct. Thats y I thought if i can calculate outside the SQL.. i can control the rounding

Comment: You mean it comes direct from a SQLDataSource object? Anyway will SQL will only truncate/round your values if you don't use the correct data type for the column.

Comment: @ADyson i'm amending this report which was develop by other developer.. and I cannot change the data type.. or add another column for total.. so I need to calculate outside.. -,- to insert and calculate column for total..

Comment: If you don't have access to modify the SQL query you could potentially add an intermediate step where the SQL query result is read into a DataTable instead of directly onto the gridview. You just need to get creative...

Comment: @ADyson yeah.. trying to be creative by calculate inside the gridview.. huhuhu..I try to avoid changes at few places and if only i can just calculate at the gridview.. it will be simple.. or so I thought.. let me try again.. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lTotal" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Room")) + Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Pos")) + Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Shower"))) %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

C#

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
             Label lTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lTotal");

            if (decimal.TryParse(lShower.Text, out amount))
                  totalSales+= amount;

    }
 else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", totalRoomSales);
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", totalPosSales);
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", totalShowerSales);
        e.Row.Cells[5].Text = string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", totalSales);
     }
```

Comment: owhh.. can calculate inside label like that?.. owh.. let me try